# find an expression for f(g(x)) in the form of $p(x + q)^2 + r$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Can somebody check my workings for the following question:

> Functions f and g are defined on suitable domains by
>
> ${f(x) = 10 + x}$ and ${g(x) = (1 + x)(3 - x) + 2}$
>
> (a) Find an expression for ${f(g(x))}$

${g(x) = (x + 1)(-x + 3) + 2}$

${g(x) = -x^2 +2x +5}$

${f(g(x)) = -x^2 + 2x + 15}$

> (b) express f(g(x)) in the form p(x + q)^2 + r

${f(g(x)) = -x^2 + 2x + 15}$

=> ${-(x^2 -2 -15)}$

=> ${-[(x -1)^2 -1 -15]}$

=> ${-(x -1)^2 + 16}$

> (c) Another function is given by ${h(x) = {1\over {f(g(x))}}}$ What
>   values of x cannot be in the domain of h?

All I can think of is h cannot be 0 because you cannot divide by 0.

Comment: You have a mistake in part (a). When you multiply $(x+1)(-x+3)$, you should get $-x^2+2x+3$. For part (c), you need to find the value(s) of $x$ such that $f(g(x))=0$.

Comment: @TimThayer thank you, I have updated the question.   How would I find the values for part c?

Comment: In part (b), you found $f(g(x))$. Just set your expression in (b) equal to 0 and solve. You will get $x=-3$ or $x=5$, which are your restricted values for part (c).

Comment: Your phrasing for (c) is incorrect, it should be that $f(g(x))$ cannot be zero because you cannot divide by 0.